# Regular expression to parse sequence IDs

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I'm having a bit of trouble with using regular expressions to extract information from flat files
(just text). The files are structured as such:

#### #

ID (e.g. >YAL001C)

Annotations/metadata (short phrases describing origin of ID)

Sequence (very long string of characters, e.g. KRHDE .... ~500 letters on average)

#### #

I am trying to extract only IDs and sequences (skip all the metadata). Unfortunately, list 
operations alone don't suffice, e.g.

```
with open("composition.in","rb") as all_info:
    all_info=all_info.read() 
    all_info=all_info.split(">")[1:]
```

because the metadata/annotation part of the text is littered with '>' characters that 
cause the list that is generated to be incorrectly structured. List comprehensions get very
ugly after a certain point, so I am trying the following:

```
with open("composition.in","rb") as yeast_all:
yeast_all=yeast_all.read() # convert file to string

## Regular expression to clean up rogue ">" characters
## i.e. "<i>", "<sub>", etc which screw up
## the structure of the eveuntual list
import re
id_delimeter = r'^>{1}+\w{7,10}+\s' 
match=re.search(id_delimeter, yeast_all)
if match:
    print 'found', match.group()
else:
    print 'did not find'        
yeast_all=yeast_all.split(id_delimeter)[1:]
```

I get only an error message saying "error: multiple repeat"

The IDs are of type:

> YAL001C
>
> YGR103W
>
> YKL068W-A

The first character is always ">", followed by capital letters and numbers and sometimes dashes
(-). I would like a RE that could be used to find all such occurrences and split the text 
using the RE as a delimeter in order to get IDs and sequences and leave out metadata. I am new to regular expressions so have limited knowledge of the topic!

Note: Only a single newline between each of the three fields (ID, metadata, sequence)

Comment: what you do think `{n}+` means given that `{n}` means n repetitions and `+` means one or more repetitions?

Comment: @isedev In this context I thought + was a concatenation. If + means >=1 repetitions, then perhaps    r'^>{1}\w{7,10}\s' would match the ids?

Comment: yes, that will probably match what you want :)  note that `{1}` is redundant (`>` by itself means a repetition of 1 - if you can call that a repetition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
>(?P<id>[\w-]+)\s.*\n(?P<sequence>[\w\n]+)
```

You'll find the ID in the group `id`and the sequence in the group `sequence`.

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/wC3kO3/4)

Explanation:

```
> # start with a ">" character
(?P<id> # capture the ID in group "id"
    [\w-]+ # this matches any number (>1) of word characters (A to Z, a to z, digits, and _) or dashes "-"
)
\s+ # after the ID, there must be at least one whitespace character
.* # consume the metadata part, we have no interest in this
\n # up to a newline
(?P<sequence> # finally, capture the sequence data in group "sequence"
    [\w\n]+ # this matches any number (>1) of word characters and newlines.
)
```

As python code:

```
text= '''>YKL068W-A
foo
ABCD

>XYZ1234
<><><><>><<<>
LMNOP'''

pattern= '>(?P<id>[\w-]+)\n.*\n(?P<sequence>\w+)'

for id, sequence in re.findall(pattern, text):
    print((id, sequence))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the website, very useful! I haven't yet managed to work out a regex for the task, here's a clearer picture of what I'm attempting: http://regex101.com/r/mH4yW5/1 I need the first sequence ID (2 matches instead of just 1) and the very long string of capital letters. Thanks again!

Comment: @Spyros: I've updated my answer, I hope it fits your requirements now. I assumed the asterisk `*` is not supposed to be a part of the sequence data.

Comment: Perfect, thanks again! So, (>P<xyz>) denotes the start of a capturing group xyz, whose pattern is to be specified immediately after. Many thanks for your time!